# Using unnest as a field rather than a table in jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

This is the query I am trying to run in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE id IN (
    SELECT unnest(message_ids) "mid"
        FROM session_messages WHERE session_id = '?' ORDER BY "mid" ASC
);
```

However, I am not able do something:

```
create.selectFrom(Tables.MESSAGE).where(Tables.MESSAGE.ID.in(
    create.select(DSL.unnest(..))
```

Because `DSL.unnest` is a `Table<?>`, which makes sense since it is trying to take a `List`-like object (mostly a literal) and convert it to table.

I have a feeling that I need to find a way to wrap the function around my field name, but I have no clue as to how to proceed.

NOTE. The field `message_ids` is of type `bigint[]`.

EDIT

So, this is how I am doing it now, and it works exactly as expected, but I am not sure if this is the best way to do it:

```
Field<Long> unnestMessageIdField = DSL.field(
                "unnest(" +  SESSION_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_IDS.getName() + ")",
                Long.class)
        .as("mid");

Field<Long> messageIdField = DSL.field("mid", Long.class);

MESSAGE.ID.in(
        ctx.select(messageIdField).from(
            ctx.select(unnestMessageIdField)
               .from(Tables.CHAT_SESSION_MESSAGES)
                    .where(Tables.CHAT_SESSION_MESSAGES.SESSION_ID.eq(sessionId))
            )
            .where(condition)
)
```

EDIT2

After going through the code on https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/DSL.java I guess the right way to do this would be:

```
DSL.function("unnest", SQLDataTypes.BIGINT.getArrayType(), SESSION_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_IDS)
```

EDIT3

Since as always lukas is here for my jOOQ woes, I am going to capitalize on this :)

Trying to generalize this function, in a signature of sort

```
public <T> Field<T> unnest(Field<T[]> arrayField) {
    return DSL.function("unnest", <??>, arrayField);
}
```

I don't know how I can fetch the datatype. There seems to be a way to get `DataType<T[]>` from `DataType<T>` using `DataType::getArrayDataType()`, but the reverse is not possible. There is this class I found `ArrayDataType`, but it seems to be package-private, so I cannot use it (and even if I could, it does not expose the field `elementType`).

Comment: What PostgreSQL version are you using?

Comment: Currently using 9.4 (Also, could you please see EDIT3, pretty please?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old PostgreSQL versions had this funky idea that it is OK to produce a table from within the `SELECT` clause, and expand it into the "outer" table, as if it were declared in the `FROM` clause. That is a very obscure PostgreSQL legacy, and this example is a good chance to get rid of it, and use `LATERAL` instead. Your query is equivalent to this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM message 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT "mid"
    FROM session_messages 
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(message_ids) AS t("mid")
    WHERE session_id = '?' 
);
```

This can be translated to jOOQ much more easily as:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select()
   .from(MESSAGE)
   .where(MESSAGE.ID).in(
        select(field(name("mid"), MESSAGE.ID.getDataType()))
       .from(SESSION_MESSAGES)
       .crossJoin(lateral(unnest(SESSION_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_IDS)).as("t", "mid"))
       .where(SESSION_MESSAGES.SESSION_ID.eq("'?'"))
   )
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that your solution seems structurally better, is there a performance difference between the two methods? And as always, thank you so much for taking the time.

Comment: Interestingly, your approach seems to produce simpler execution plans. You'll have to measure (or ask another question!)

Answer (score 2):

The `Edit3` in the question is quite close to a decent solution for this problem.
We can create a custom generic `unnest` method for jOOQ which accepts `Field` and use it in jOOQ query normally.

**Helper method:**

```
public static <T> Field<T> unnest(Field<T[]> field) {
    var type = (Class<T>) field.getType().getComponentType();
    return DSL.function("unnest", type, field);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public void query(SessionId sessionId) {

    var field = unnest(SESSION_MESSAGES.MESSAGE_IDS, UUID.class);

    dsl.select().from(MESSAGE).where(
            MESSAGE.ID.in(
                dsl.select(field).from(SESSION_MESSAGES)
                .where(SESSION_MESSAGES.SESSION_ID.eq(sessionId.id))
                .orderBy(field)
            )
    );

}
```

Comment: You don't have to pass that `type` argument, you can get it directly from `field.getType().getComponentType()` (with an unsafe cast)

Comment: ie `var type = (Class<T>) field.getType().getComponentType();` in the helper method.